# ClearCase find command issue in finding latest files doesn't have the label

Tags: find, clearcase

I want to find all elements in a directory in ClearCase under a branch say `BR1` where the label `LABEL1` is not on latest of `BR1`.

```
cleartool find . -ele "lbtype_sub(LABEL1) && brtype(BR1) && ! version(.../BR1/LATEST)" -print
```

This doesn't seem to be working.
What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example of [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) for versions *not* the LATEST is:

```
cleartool find . -version "{brtype(main_dev) && created_since(30-Apr) &&  
  (! created_since(31-May)) && (! version(\main\main_dev\LATEST))}" -print
```

So try:

```
cleartool find . -ele '{lbtype_sub(LABEL1) && brtype(BR1) && (! version(.../BR1/LATEST))}' -print
```

---

If it doesn't work for elements, **do the query for version associated with an exec directive, in order to display the name of the element associated with the version found**:
(see [`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc%255Fref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm))

```
cleartool find . -ver '{lbtype_sub(LABEL1) && brtype(BR1) && (! version(.../BR1/LATEST))}' -exe 'cleartool descr -fmt "%En"'
```

And sort the list to remove any duplicate: `%En` display the name of the *element*.

**Warning: Note that will give you elements that *also* have a LATEST version on that branch `BR1`**, so you need to make a *second* query:

```
cleartool find . -ver '{lbtype_sub(LABEL1) && brtype(BR1) && version(.../BR1/LATEST)}' -exe 'cleartool descr -fmt "%En"'
```

That will give you all the elements which have a version in `BR1/LATEST`.
Remove those elements from the first list, and you will get (finally) what you are after.

In short: `-ele` doesn't work directly for this kind of query.

Comment: sorry forgot to say this was for linux and the above did not work

Comment: @user2636464 sure: replace double quotes by simple quotes, but the answer stands

Comment: not sure but it doesn't give any results whereas this one gives cleartool find . -ver '{lbtype_sub(LABEL1) && brtype(BR1) && (! version(.../BR1/LATEST))}' -print. But i am not interested in version but in element.

Comment: @user2636464 Then do it for versions, display the name of the element and remove duplicates: see my edited answer.